# Windows 10 - in "Open File" dialog, jump to selected file in Explorer window

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

Back in the day I had an add-on for XP that would make any "open file" dialog jump to the location of a file if you selected it in an explorer window.

So if you had a deeply nested file visible in an explorer window, and you decided you wanted to open it in applicationX.exe and you used the **file>open** menu in that application, rather than having to navigate to the file, all you had to do was select it in the Explorer window and the dialog would instantly jump to the location of the file. A bit like the way in OSX you used to be able to drag a file from a Finder window to an "open file" dialog to jump to its location.

I'm trying to find out if it still exists, but I can't remember what it was called, and duckduckgoing for "[open file dialog click explorer jump to location](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=open%20file%20dialog%20click%20explorer%20jump%20to%20location&t=ffab&ia=qa)" or such like yields far to much noise to be able to find any signal.

Is there such a thing for Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

I found the add-on, it's called [File Box Extender](http://www.hyperionics.com/index.asp). It's unsupported and not tested for Windows > Vista, but the developers have released the source, and the binary that I downloaded does seem to be working on Windows 10, creators update.