# Synchronise/jump to path between explorer and file dialog

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I have been using a launcher application ([Listary](https://www.listary.com/)), however, it hasn't been updated in a long time and I would like to stop using it as it tends to eat memory for breakfast.

However, it has a useful feature that I use many times a day, and that is if you have a normal file explorer window open, and you also have a file dialogue open (e.g. saving or opening a file in an application), then Listary will synchronise/jump to the same folder in your file dialogue.

It's a bit hard to explain in text, so [here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9T9-OtRVeUw) showing what it does, along with a screenshot:

[image]

So my question is, what could I use to replicate this without using Listary?
I've tried searching but the only thing I came up with is [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1329263/windows-10-in-open-file-dialog-jump-to-selected-file-in-explorer-window), but I'd rather not use unsupported software if possible.

Any solution is fine really, Autohotkey or a third-party application (preferably free/O/S).

Comment: I continue using Listary only for this feature. Did you find any alternative?

Answer (score 3):

Try this Autohotkey script:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
#Persistent

; create a group of the file dialogue windows
GroupAdd, file_dialogue_Group, Open ahk_class #32770
GroupAdd, file_dialogue_Group, Save As ahk_class #32770

SetTimer, ExplorerPathInFileDialogue, 300  ; check every 300 ms
Return

ExplorerPathInFileDialogue: 
    If !WinActive("ahk_group file_dialogue_Group")  ; "!" means "NOT" in this case
        return  ; do nothing
    If !WinExist("ahk_class CabinetWClass") ; explorer
        return
    ; otherwise:
    SendInput, % GetExplorerPath() 
    Sleep, 100
    SendInput, {Enter}{Del}
    SetTimer, ExplorerPathInFileDialogue, Off
    WinWaitClose, ahk_group file_dialogue_Group
    SetTimer, ExplorerPathInFileDialogue, On
Return

GetExplorerPath(){
    for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
    {
       explorer_path := ""
       try explorer_path := window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
       if (explorer_path != "")
            return explorer_path
    }
}
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm